# Symfony 2 odbc component

Tags: php, symfony, odbc, teradata

Just configuring my Standard Symfony2 edition to be used with the odbc driver. I need that for the Teradata connection.

I completely don't need any ORM tools, I will only use it to return the results from the Teradata Stored Procedure or complex query.

Currently it works in the procedural PHP code by following few simple steps:

```
 - $conn   = odbc_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD)
 - $stmt   = odbc_prepare($conn, $query)
 - $params = array(1, 2, 3)
 - odbc_execute($stmt, $params)
 - next just fetch results using odbc_fetch_array($stmt)
```

Just thinking now about how and where to implement this in the Symfony2 MVC stack according to the Sf2 best practices... Perhaps a separate service?

Will only mention that the ease of use for fresh developers is a priority.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you as well use PDO ODBC? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php - PDO is normally used in the PHP world nowadays so you might find components that exist already and only need your configuration and that's it.

Comment: Quote from another website:
"You may be out of luck.
- PDO doesn't have a native driver
- ADODb doesn't have a native driver"
But yeah, using PDO for pretty much everything since years...apart from Teradata...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe I would suggest creating a service which, instead of using global constants receives `HOST`, `USER` and `PASSWORD` via Service Container, i.e. you store that information in your parameters.yml, create a service with these parameters in your bundle's service.yml and finally you create your Service-class which basically just wraps your odbc-calls.

This way you can keep the sensitive data (user, password) out of your git-repo, assuming you are not tracking parameters.yml as is suggested in Symfony's documentation and you can easily access your service from everywhere where you have access to the Service Container like this:

`$this->getContainer()->get('acme_demo.teradata_service')`

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    teradata_host:     localhost
    teradata_user:     username
    teradata_password: password
```

Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\config\services.yml:

```
services:
    acme_demo.teradata_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\TeradataService
        arguments:
            - %teradata_host%
            - %teradata_user%
            - %teradata_password%
```

Acme\DemoBundle\Service\TeradataService:

```
class TeradataService
{
    public function __construct($host, $user, $password) 
    ...
}
```

You could even go further and make the teradata service private in your service.yml and then just create other services which access your TeradataService. This way you can make sure, that deleopers do not interfere with the service directly, but only via ObjectManagers.

Acme\DemoBundle\Resources\config\services.yml:

```
services:
    acme_demo.teradata_service:
        public: false
        class:  Acme\DemoBundle\Service\TeradataService
        arguments:
            - %teradata_host%
            - %teradata_user%
            - %teradata_password%

    acme_demo.another_service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\ServiceAccessingTeradata
        arguments:
            - @acme_demo.teradata_service
```

This way your services are not bound to your teradata-connection directly, which makes it easier to replace Acme\DemoBundle\Service\TeradataService with something else.

Comment: Hey, sorry for delay, this sounds fantastic (especially second option!),
I'm giving +1 and if manage to glue it all together - green check ;)
Thanks a lot!!!